# Round IO Double to specified number of digits - Haskell

Tags: haskell, rounding, monads

Is there a way to round `IO Double`? I looking for a function:

```
ownRound :: IO Double -> IO Double
```

with these Unit tests:

```
ownRound 0.51 == 0.5
ownRound 0.49 == 0.5
ownRound 0.5 == 0.5
ownRound 0.7132 == 0.7
ownRound 0.39 == 0.4
```

Comment: `fmap :: (a -> b) -> (IO a -> IO b)` is possible.

Comment: @AJFarmar, yep, I got it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are asking for can't be had. The test cases you've written are for the function

```
tensRound :: Double -> Double
```

but the type signature you wrote is for the function

```
ownRound :: IO Double -> IO Double
```

If you meant to write your test cases as

```
ownRound (return 0.51) == return 0.5
ownRound (return 0.49) == return 0.5
```

and so on, where every number is wrapped into IO, then these implementations would work:

```
tensRound :: Double -> Double
tensRound d = fromInteger (round (d*10)) / 10

ownRound :: IO Double -> IO Double
ownRound = fmap tensRound
```